# Exponential objects and hom-sets.

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a cartesian closed category and $X, Y$ two objects of $C$.

Is it the case that $\text{Hom}(X,Y) = Y^X$?

Comment: Well, $hom$ is always a functor into the category of sets, and $Y^X$ is an object of $\mathbf{C}$... So only if $\mathbf{C=Set}$.

Answer (score 5):

No, since $\hom(X,Y)$ is a set, but $Y^X$ is an object of $C$.

The relation between these two guys is  given by the following formula (where $1$ denotes a terminal object):
$$\hom(1,Y^X) \cong \hom(X,Y).$$
This bijection follows immediately from the definitions.

In other words, $Y^X$ is an object whose set of "global sections" is $\hom(X,Y)$. This is true verbatim if $C$ is a Grothendieck topos.

Comment: What if OP meant 'internal hom' with $\operatorname{Hom}$?

Comment: @Andy: Well, "internal hom" is just another word for "exponential object". I assumed that the question is non-empty, not just asking if A=A.